# Asymptotic normality of an estimator

Tags: probability, self-study, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

Suppose an exponential distribution :
$$ f(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x} $$
The MLE for theta is the inverse of the sample mean :
$$ \frac{1}{\bar{X}} $$

I want to find the asymptotic normality of this estimator by using the property that theta is asymptotically normal  :
$$ \hat{\theta} \sim AN \bigg(\theta,\frac{1}{nI(\theta)} \bigg) $$
With $I(\theta)$ the Fisher information :
$$ I(\theta)=\operatorname{E} \left[\left. \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2\theta} \log f_X(x;\theta)\right)\right ) \theta \right] $$
I found :
$$ I(\theta)=E\bigg(\frac{1}{\theta^2}\bigg) $$

I propose that $\hat{\theta} $ is  asymptotically distributed as follows :
$$ \hat{\theta} \sim AN\bigg(\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{n}\bigg) $$

Does the following equation also true ? Am I missing something ?
$$\sqrt n\ \frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\theta} \sim N(0,1)  $$

Comment: mistake #1: you used the $n$-sample information rather than the $1$-sample information, which explains for the $n^2$. mistake #2: the asymptotic (limiting) distribution should not have any $n$ appearing.

Comment: So $\hat{\theta} \sim AN(\theta,\theta^2/n) $ would be correct ? What do you mean by "the asymptotic distribution shouldn't have any $n$ appearing ?

Comment: I'm still not understanding why you are saying that the asymptotic distribution should not have any $n$ appearing. In the formulary, the professor states explicitely that the n-sample information should be used instead of the 1-sample information. see : https://imgur.com/a/gJgWLwJ

Comment: Hi: If you take the parameters out of your AN expression and put them over to the LHS, you'll get the same expression as the last expression. So, there's nothing wrong theoretically. As far as your question to Xian, he means that, generally speaking, when you write asymptotic expressions, you keep the n's on the LHS. If you don't, then you can end up with degenerate RV's.